# my first conan package not getting found by CMAKE?

Tags: c++, cmake, conan

I have seemingly successfully built my first local conan package and uploaded it to my local artifactory.. I can also add it by full name in the dependencies of other projects like so..

```
[requires]
thrift/0.13.0
mypkg/0.0.1@user/channel

[generators]
cmake
```

I can link it without error likeso in my `OtherProject` CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
project(OtherProject)
add_compile_options(-std=c++11)

# Using the "cmake" generator
include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
conan_basic_setup(TARGETS)

add_executable(OtherProject src/Main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(OtherProject CONAN_PKG::my-pkg)
```

but when I attempt to reference this in my consuming project's C++ it fails to find the `mypkg.a` file or any headers I expect to be available to it?  Did I build my recipe incorrectly?  Or am I just needing to change how I reference my new conan package in my code ?

**OtherProject/consumingHeader.H**

```
#pragma once
#include "MyPkgsHeader.h"
```

**Error on build**

```
> cmake --build .
Scanning dependencies of target OtherProject
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/OtherProject.dir/src/Main.cpp.o
In file included from /OtherProject/src/Main.cpp:12:
/OtherProject/src/TestCppClient.h:8:10: fatal error: 'MyPkgsHeader.h' file not found
#include "MyPkgsHeader.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/OtherProject.dir/src/Main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/OtherProject.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

**MyPkg Recipe conanfile.py**

```
from conans import ConanFile, CMake, tools


class MyPkgConan(ConanFile):
    name = "mypkg"
    version = "0.0.1"
    license = "<Put the package license here>"
    author = "<Put your name here> <And your email here>"
    url = "<Package recipe repository url here, for issues about the package>"
    description = "<Description of mypkg here>"
    topics = ("<Put some tag here>", "<here>", "<and here>")
    settings = "os", "compiler", "build_type", "arch"
    options = {"shared": [True, False]}
    default_options = {"shared": False}
    generators = "cmake"

    def source(self):
        self.run("git clone --depth 1 --branch 0.0.1 git@github.com:PROJECT/my-pkg.git")

        tools.replace_in_file("my-pkg/CMakeLists.txt", "         LANGUAGES CXX )",
                              '''         LANGUAGES CXX )
add_compile_options(-std=c++11)''')

    def build(self):
        cmake = CMake(self)
        cmake.configure(source_folder="my-pkg")
        cmake.build()

        # Explicit way:
        # self.run('cmake %s/hello %s'
        #          % (self.source_folder, cmake.command_line))
        # self.run("cmake --build . %s" % cmake.build_config)

    def package(self):
        self.copy("*.h", dst="include", src="my-pkg")
        self.copy("*hello.lib", dst="lib", keep_path=False)
        self.copy("*.dll", dst="bin", keep_path=False)
        self.copy("*.so", dst="lib", keep_path=False)
        self.copy("*.dylib", dst="lib", keep_path=False)
        self.copy("*.a", dst="lib", keep_path=False)

    def package_info(self):
        self.cpp_info.libs = ["mypkg"]
```

#EDIT: Seeing a problem with includes folder

As instructed I took a look at my `conanbuildinfo.cmake` and specifically looked for the path under `CONAN_INCLUDE_DIRS_MY-PKG`

the source files are in a folder structure I didn't expect

```
/../<conanhash>/include/source/cppclient/client/MyPkgsHeader.h
```

when I was expected perhaps

```
/../<conanhash>/client/MyPkgsHeader.h

or

/../<conanhash>/MyPkgsHeader.h
```

Sounds like I need to change my recipe a bit...

Comment: I would recommend inspecting the generated ``conanbuildinfo.cmake`` file, and then check the folders the INCLUDE_DIRS variables, and check if the headers are actually inside that folder. If they are not, I would check the package creation process (the ``test_package`` functionality is extremely recommended to automate this). You can start with a ``conan new hello/0.1 -s -t`` that works and test the package, and then customize it for your own code.

Comment: I indeed found my `INCLUDE_DIRS_MY-PKG` .. went into the folder... and found that the folder structure is perhaps not what it should be... I think i need to somehow make the root folder a sub-folder of it's current setting..

will add this detail now to post

Comment: thank you drodri, I got it.. can you post this basically that I had to change this line in my recipe to get the files copied in a correct manner?

```
        self.copy("*.h", dst="include", src="my-pkg/source/cppclient/client")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right process to debug this kind of problems is the following:

- Check the generated **conanbuildinfo.cmake** file, it will contain variables like CONAN_INCLUDE_DIRS pointing to folders in the Conan cache, that should contain the expected headers.
- If you cannot identify the variables in the **conanbuildinfo.cmake** that belongs to your missing dependency, it might be that you are missing a `requires = "pkg/version..."` in your recipe, or to execute `conan install` again to fetch that dependency and generate a new **conanbuildinfo.cmake**
- Navigate to those folders, check if the expected headers are there. If they are not, it seems that the package was incorrectly created. You need to go back to the recipe that created that package, fix it and execute `conan create` again
- Most common problems while packaging the final artifacts is some wrong pattern or path in the `self.copy()` calls inside the [`package()` method](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/methods.html#package). For headers the call would be something like `self.copy("*.h", dst="include", src="<path/to/headers>")`, where the `src` argument could be wrong.
- It is possible to go to the Conan cache folder and navigate inside after a `conan create` and check manually if the expected files are there.

In order to avoid problems of incorrectly created packages, it is very recommended to use the `test_package` functionality. In short it is a "consumer" project, together with the package recipe that will be automatically fired when `conan create`, and it will install+build+execute whatever app you tell it, to make some basic checks about the package and fail as early as possible if not correct. Check the ["test_package" docs](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/creating_packages/getting_started.html#the-test-package-folder)